# Finding value of a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> **Question:** Find the value of: $$\frac{100}{\ln2}\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{99}}{(1+x)(1+x^{100})}dx$$

I'm not sure where how to approach this question. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

**hint**: write $1 - x^{99} = (1+ x^{100}) - x^{99}(1+x)$

Comment: Aha.... yep got it now. May I ask how you thought of this? My brain just doesn't seem to function the right way.

Comment: Hmmm.... so if I have two terms in the denominator, especially with such large exponential values, I should think of splitting the numerator somehow so that one of the terms in the denominator cancels out?

Comment: The general technique here is sometimes called "partial fractions" and is often useful for integrating rational functions. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).